# Javascript regex help

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anybody know how I can make the forwardslash and format: dd/mm/yyyy compulsory in this regex?

```
// Checks a string to see if it in a valid date format
// of (D)D/(M)M/(YY)YY and returns true/false
function isValidDate(s) {
    // format D(D)/M(M)/(YY)YY
    var dateFormat = /^\d{1,4}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,2}[\.|\/|-]\d{1,4}$/;
    if (dateFormat.test(s)) {
        // remove any leading zeros from date values
        s = s.replace(/0*(\d*)/gi,"$1");
        var dateArray = s.split(/[\.|\/|-]/);
              // correct month value
        dateArray[1] = dateArray[1]-1;
        // correct year value
        if (dateArray[2].length<4) {
            // correct year value
            dateArray[2] = (parseInt(dateArray[2]) < 50) ? 2000 + parseInt(dateArray[2]) : 1900 + parseInt(dateArray[2]);
        }
        var testDate = new Date(dateArray[2], dateArray[1], dateArray[0]);
        if (testDate.getDate()!=dateArray[0] || testDate.getMonth()!=dateArray[1] || testDate.getFullYear()!=dateArray[2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=date

Answer (score 1):

for mandatory dd/mm/yyyy try:

```
 var dateFormat = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

I didn't look to closely at the rest of the function, but I think that is what you were going for.

Comment: *hehe* .. same thing same time :)

Answer (score 0):

this would do it i think..

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/
```

forced 2 digit days, 2 digit months, 4 digit years and / as seperator..

or

```
/^[0-3][0-9]\/[0-1][0-9]\/\d{4}$/
```

to enforce a little bounds control..
***day***: 00-39
**month**: 00-19